# Microsoft Entra provisioning is sending empty request bodies to the POST /Users/ endpoint when creating user

Tags: azure, scim, microsoft-entra-id

I'm currently trying to implement SCIM provisioning in Microsoft Entra ID. I have set up the /Users endpoint, and Entra seems to be able to detect that and begin the provisioning process. However, it keeps failing with errors from my server. When I look into the POST requests being sent to create users, the request body is *empty*. So then my server fails certain validations it expects. Has anyone else run into this problem and found a solution? For context I'm running a node express server, and `req.body` keeps evaluating to `{}`. So it's not that the field doesn't exist, there's just nothing in it. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that the reason express wasn't reading it was because the default body parser only reads content type `application/json`, and Entra sends `application/scim+json`. So you need to add a body parser to your express router to handle type `application/scim+json`, and then it will appear in `req.body`. Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same issue.